# Lifetime of return value not directly related to parameter lifetime

Tags: rust, design-patterns

I am new to rust, and having trouble figuring out the correct design pattern for what I am trying to do. In my program, there are Position structs, which reference a single coordinate system that they "belong" to. I have understood that rust must therefore be able to guarantee that `coordinate_system` reference outlives the `Position`. So far so good.

The issue is in a function such as `transform_to_parent`, where I want to create a new `Position` which is dependent on the lifetime of the exact `coordinate_system` that it later references, and not on the lifetime of the `self` parameter through which it accesses the coordinate system. This seems to be the only thing that lifetime specifiers would allow.

If I add a lifetime specifier to the following code, it compiles, but understandably complains when I let the old Position that I transformed from goes out of scope.

```rust
pub struct Position<'a> {
    // Position data omitted
    coordinate_system: &'a CoordinateSystem<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Position<'a> {
    fn transform_to_parent<'b>(self: &'b Self) -> Option<Position<'b>> {
        Some(Position {
            coordinate_system: self.coordinate_system.origin?.coordinate_system
        })
    }
}

pub struct CoordinateSystem<'a> {
    origin: Option<&'a Position<'a>>,
} 

// Test case
fn main() {
    // child_system is the child coordinate system of root_system, and has its origin at child_origin
    let root_system = CoordinateSystem { origin: None };
    let child_origin = Position { coordinate_system: &root_system };
    let child_system = CoordinateSystem { origin: Some(&child_origin) };

    let mut p2 = Position { coordinate_system: &child_system };
    {
        let p1 = Position { coordinate_system: &child_system };
        if let Some(x) = p1.transform_to_parent() { // Error: "borrowed value does not live long enough"
            p2 = x;
        }
    }
    // No-op, just pretend to use p2 again, after p1 has gone out of scope
    p2;
}
```

Is it possible for Rust to bind the lifetime of the function result to the lifetime of `self.coordinate_system.get_origin()?.coordinate_system` (i.e. the parent coordinate system), instead of the `self`? Is there a correct design pattern for something like this?

I assume that a ref-counting system would work, but I think that would be bad design, because there is clear ownership of the coordinate systems, and because the lifetime information should be deducible *somehow*.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: I've included an example showing the error when compiled. I don't think I can trim it down much further.

Comment: @lte678 That's minimal enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `'a` lifetime from the field:

```rust
impl<'a> Position<'a> {
    fn transform_to_parent(&self) -> Option<Position<'a>> {
        Some(Position {
            coordinate_system: self.coordinate_system.origin?.coordinate_system
        })
    }
}
```